# How to display table created using multiple type input values from a form to another page after hitting submit button?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have written two javascript functions and want to use both of them when I hit submit button. This is a form. First function is already embedded in the submit button. It displays a paragraph when you hit the submit button. Now, I want to display a table containing field values from the form (types - date, text, number). This is a 2 colmn and 5 rows table. In first column, the values are company name, number of seats available, names of the positions, location, last date for application And the second column contains the field values taken from the input in the form using document.getElementById('ID') function. Both the functions use document.getElementById('ID').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, I'd recommend using jQuery for this as it gets more simplified.

In this [example](https://api.jquery.com/submit/), they show you how to override a basic form. In that handler you could place your two functions.

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevents the actual sending of a form
  myFunction1(); // call your first function
  myFunction2(); // call your second function
});
```

If I understand correctly, you have both of those functions implemented already, you're just looking for a way to call them?

Also the actual changing of the text/content is done by a simple

```
$('#elementID').html('The new changed content'); // if it's a div or something alike
$('#elementID').val('The new changed content'); // if it's an input
```

I hope this answers your question :-)

Comment: So instead of using java script you want me to use jQuery. If I do so, do I need to only make changes in place of JS or I need to make changes in input codes too.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to make changes elsewhere, but I'd strongly recommend doing so, because it's cleaner and more professional. The code will become cleaner and more easy to read and modify. jQuery is the way to go and has a great documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using JQuery but if you cant all you have to do is call your JavaScript function within the first function.

```
    function myFunction1(){
            //Your code that displays a paragraph.
            myFunction2();
            }

    function myFunction2(){
            //code body of function 2
            }
```

So if your first function is already embedded in the submit button now your code will execute by displaying the paragraph and then execute the second functions code. 
But it is alot cleaner and less 'hacky' to use JQuery like Mr Frogurt expalined above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes I tries that. But the problem is after Function2() I have to define the function. It looks like this function function1(){.....some body of program from function1.....}

Comment: And after these .....some body of program from function1.....
          function function2(){}

Comment: sorry, function function2(){
........body of the second program.....
}         //both brackets close
}

Now what I don't understand is whether it is allowed to define the function there or not. And do I need to add ; after first } or remove function keyword from the second function2.

Comment: I have revised my answer is that what you mean? You can call the function within another function. Just like the way you called the function from the button

Comment: No no... DON'T TAKE IT WRONG... I was humbly saying asking for whether I can define that second function within the body of the second function and if so then do I need to apply ; after the } of the second function.

Comment: Dont worry I didnt take it wrong lol, You can not define a function within another function but you can call a function from another function. So you can do what I did above in my answer. Any other questions please ask :) and if I have been helpful could you upvote my answer please